# How can I automatically start a LAN connection?

Tags: linux, android, arduino-galileo, ssh, lan

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 with JuiceSSH installed. I also have Debian Linux installed via chroot. I'll be ordering an Intel Galileo to use as a portable compilation server. I have an attachment for the Note 10.1 that serves as a USB and an ethernet adapter. I figure I could power the Note 10.1 with the USB port and connect to it via SSH through the ethernet port.

Unfortunately, [this post](https://communities.intel.com/thread/46335) notes that in order to connect the Galileo via ssh, the LAN connection must be started manually through Arduino Sketch.

I'd like to install Debian Linux on the Galileo, get rid of my chroot Debian on my tablet, and have that LAN connection started automatically when the Galileo boots so that I can just connect to it through JuiceSSH on my tablet. This is so I can do everything without depending on WiFi and compile "offline". How do I automatically start the LAN connection and avoid having to use Arduino Sketch?

Also, does anyone know if ArduinoDroid works on the Galileo?